# Substrings of string unions using template literal types

Tags: typescript

I have a union of a bunch of different strings, which represent all the translation keys supported by the application. They are written in a standardized form, with `'.'`'s as separators. For example:

```
type Keys = 'foo.bar' | 'baz.bar' | 'fail.error';
```

I would like to derive from that union another union, which contains all the root strings that end in `.bar`. So for this example, the desired output is `'foo' | 'baz'`

My best solution so far is as follows, but it requires me to always explicitly state the string as a parameter to the generic:

```
type Namespace<T extends string = string> = `${T}.bar` extends Keys ? T : never;

const example0: Namespace<'foo'> = 'foo'; // Allowed, but i had to explicitly give the type
const example1: Namespace<'notFound'> = 'notFound'; // Correctly gives an error
```

I would like to be able to do the following, but my current version results in an error on each line:

```
const example2: Namespace = 'foo'; // Should be allowed, but isn't
const example3: Namespace = 'baz'; // Should be allowed, but isn't
const example4: Namespace = 'fail'; // Should be an error
const example5: Namespace = 'notFound'; // Should be an error
```

Is there a better way i can do this type?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201028#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)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLly2m) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  Note that it is conventional to write types in UpperPascalCase, so I've changed `keys` to `Keys`.

Comment: Yes, that looks like it will work. I experimented with `infer`, but wasn't able to get it to work. If you write it up, i'll accept

Comment: Another general option could be [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA1hIGcoF4oHIBmB7LA6ARgIYBOaUAPukQF4ElmWaECWANrhMcVqQNwCwAKCGhIUAKIA7ACYIA6s2AALADwAVADQSZzSQHMoEAB7AIMpAmDFdegHwooawybOyoAAwAkAb10ZOUABKOMAAvrg+fgEACtxgoe5CUMnJAPxQsVhgzqbm2tI2SSnFaUEhRSUpAFxQkhAAbpwVyTV1jcQCwoKi0IEOUrIKyipwiFpoRKS2nQD0MykAeqlAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach here would be to create a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where we first create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `Keys` where each key `P` has a property that is the first part of `P` if it ends in `".bar"`, or `never` otherwise.  And then we immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) this object type with `Keys` to get the `Namespace` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type we want.  This serves to distribute the operation of extracting the part before `".bar"` over the union of entries in `Keys`:

```
type Namespace = { [P in Keys]: P extends `${infer K}.bar` ? K : never }[Keys];
// type Namespace = "foo" | "baz"
```

This could be generalized if necessary to `Prefix<T, U>` which takes a union of string literals `T` and a suffix `U` and returns the prefix of the elements of `T` that are followed by the suffix `U`:

```
type Prefix<T extends string, U extends string> =
    { [P in T]: P extends `${infer K}${U}` ? K : never }[T];

type AlsoNamespace = Prefix<Keys, ".bar">
// type AlsoNamespace = "foo" | "baz"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oHIBmB7LA6ARgIYBOaUAPukQF4ElmWaECWANrhMcVqQNwCwAKCGhIUAHKEAthARhCAY2ioA3lADaABSjMAdrHgIAugC4o2iAA9gEXQBMkAAwAkKvRk6wAvnWKOoAPywUGa6EABunl7qcIhGAoIA9IlQotCSMnKKylAARNhYuRR5NLlCQgpYugjAUFbSYKwQAExmGbLySijoBWi8UMlQAMoAFlgArqx2UPjQhKysWADuEHYANDPjtcwIumjAFVU1dZYNTQDMbdId2d1oNH0DKaMTUzNzC8urG-hbOrv7Q7VWr1KSNCAAFiumU6OSYbEegxek2msyghH0nG4xCBx1B4IArNCbl1UGhdFhgAAxCb2RHPMYo97ozFcHjlQRpczECAYZiWAA8ABUTjZ7EgasQ9ABzDYAVVFtgcUElMoAfCghFBtVA1FodPohaZzIrxVAXG5dB5iN5XHKvP4gjAQlAwpEbdEjQkROBoABBVgILDtLKk7m8-kC2IIDa5Xy5NVCQZcgNBkOw7r5HBFSi5UpAA)